# View doesn't expand to fit a scaled Border

Tags: silverlight, layout, rendertransform

I have a Border inside a Grid which is displayed in a ChildWindow. I need to make the Border larger so I applied a RenderTransform to it. However the ChildWindow hasn't expanded to fit the scaled Border. It looks like the size is being calculated before the render transform is applied. This means that the border is now cropped and I can only see a 1/4 of it.

I've tried wrapping the Border in a ScrollViewer and a ViewBox, neither of which have worked.

```
<Grid>
    ...
    <Border x:Name="Border"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Background="White"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            BorderThickness="1"
            CornerRadius="5"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Height="{Binding NewLabelTemplate.Height}"
            Width="{Binding NewLabelTemplate.Width}">
        <Border.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5"
                            CenterY="0.5"
                            ScaleX="2"
                            ScaleY="2"/>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
        ...
    </Border>
    ...
</Grid>
```

How can I get the ChildWindow to use the ultimate size of the border when calculating its size?

I can't apply either the scale to the ChildWindow or use the rendered height and width of the Border directly as there are other elements in the Grid that I don't want to be scaled.

Comment: Generally you want the parent to dictate that stuff for its children instead of vice versa. Why not just apply your height/width directly to the ChildWindow?

Comment: @ChrisW. because the border is only one element in the child window and I don't want the other elements to be scaled.

Comment: That's why you wouldn't want to use Scaling under the guise that scaling will interact with the sizes of anything, let alone a parent. Scaling doesn't work that way unfortunately. Either way the parent will set the panel boundary of where that scaling will be visible. So you'll have to provide space for it regardless amigo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment I can think of two possible solutions:

**1. Calculate Scaled Properties for Your Border to Bind to**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ScaledSizeProperties x:Key="BorderSizes"
            ScaleFactor="2"
            BorderThickness="1"
            CornerRadius="5"
            Height="{Binding NewLabelTemplate.Height}"
            Width="{Binding NewLabelTemplate.Width}"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    ...
    <Border x:Name="Border"
        Grid.Row="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Background="White"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        BorderThickness="{Binding
            Path=ScaledBorderThickness, Source={StaticResource BorderSizes}}"
        CornerRadius="{Binding
            Path=ScaledCornerRadius, Source={StaticResource BorderSizes}}"
        Height="{Binding
            Path=ScaledHeight, Source={StaticResource BorderSizes}}"
        Width="{Binding
            Path=ScaledWidth, Source={StaticResource BorderSizes}}">
        ...
    </Border>
    ...
</Grid>
```

and code:

```
public class ScaledSizeProperties : DependencyObject
{
    //add input DependencyProperties for:
    //double ScaleFactor
    //double BorderThickness
    //double CornerRadius
    //double Height
    //double Width

    //add output DependencyProperties for:
    //double ScaledBorderThickness
    //double ScaledCornerRadius
    //double ScaledHeight
    //double ScaledWidth

    public double ScaleFactor
    {
        get { return (double) GetValue( ScaleFactorProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( ScaleFactorProperty, value ); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ScaleFactorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "ScaleFactor", typeof( double ),
        typeof( ScaledSizeProperties ),
        new PropertyMetadata( 1, OnScaleFactorChanged ) );

    private static void OnScaleFactorChanged(DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //recalculate all size properties
    }

    public double Height
    {
        get ...
        set ...
    }

    ... DependencyProperty HeightProperty ... OnHeightChanged ...

    private static void OnHeightChanged(DependencyObject d,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //recalculate ScaledHeight
    }
}
```

**2. Use a LayoutTransformer instead of RenderTransform**

The [LayoutTransformer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.internal.pivot.controls.layouttransformer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) that is part of the Toolkit is now (since SL5) official part of the base library package of Silverlight.

```
<Grid>
...
<LayoutTransformer
    Grid.Row="3"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
        <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5"
                        CenterY="0.5"
                        ScaleX="2"
                        ScaleY="2"/>
    </LayoutTransformer.LayoutTransform>
    <Border x:Name="Border"
        Background="White"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="1"
        CornerRadius="5"
        Height="{Binding NewLabelTemplate.Height}"
        Width="{Binding NewLabelTemplate.Width}">
        ...
    </Border>
</LayoutTransformer>
...
</Grid>
```